# Add the elements of 2 rows based on pattern condition

Tags: linux, bash, awk, command

I want to add 2 rows based on a pattern

I have this table

```
1        -         513        1478          966        1  
2        -        1594        2130          537        1  
3        +        2171        2539          369        1  
4        -        2587        3159          573        1
```

What Iam looking for is to add an $7 column with the first element starts with  0 and if the $2 is "-" then substract -1 from $7 else add +1 in the $7
like this:

```
1        -         513        1478          966        1     -1  
2        -        1594        2130          537        1     -2  
3        +        2171        2539          369        1     -1  
4        -        2587        3159          573        1     -2  `
```

I wrote this

```
awk '$7==0,i=1;{for i in $1 do {if($2="-"){$7=$7+1}else{$7=$7-1} done print}'
```

The issue with my code is that if I remove the `for` condition turns the entire $2 in - and the entire $7 is -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not working at all. It complaints about a couple of syntax errors. In any case, I think you are overthinking the problem. If I didn't understood you wrong, the solution is simpler:

```
awk 'BEGIN {v=0} {if ($2=="-") {v=v-1} else {v=v+1}; $7=v; print}'
```

Use a var `v` to keep the last value and add or substract one depending on `$2` content. Once `v` is updated, assign it to `$7` and print the entire record. In the next line you already have the last valu of the seventh column in `v`.

Comment: Works perfectly!!! Thanks a lot... you are totally right. The solution was really simple. My problem is that I am new in the "club"so Im still learning.

Answer (score 2):

using @RavinderSingh13's trick

```
$ awk '{print $0 "\t" (c+=$2"1")}' file

1        -         513        1478          966        1        -1
2        -        1594        2130          537        1        -2
3        +        2171        2539          369        1        -1
4        -        2587        3159          573        1        -2
```

Comment: works superfine, and it is really simple code. I edited lit bit as my final goal was to add the values of $5 at the same time with $2 and because of your code I did it as I wish. ;-) . Thanks a lot!!!!

Answer (score 1):

This should be as simple as the following.

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t\t"} {$2=$2"1";$(NF+1)=$2*$NF+prev;prev=$NF} 1' Input_file
```

***Brief explanation:***

- Adding `1` to `$2` 2nd field value of every line.
- Multiplying value of `$2` with last field(which means multiplying `1` with +ve or -ve to last field) and saving its value to newly created last field.
- Now adding previous line's last field value to it here as per OP's question.
- Saving current last field(new created one by using `$(NF+1)`) to `prev` variable so that it could be used to add in next line's calculations.

***Detailed explanation:***

```
awk '                   ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                  ##Starting BEGIN section of this awk program from here.
  OFS="\t\t"            ##Setting value of 2 times TAB for each line here.
}                       ##Close BEGIN section of this code here.
{
  $2=$2"1"              ##Concatenating 1 to value of $2 here.
  $(NF+1)=$2*$NF+prev   ##Creating new last field whose value is $2*$NF and adding prev variable to it.
  prev=$NF              ##Setting current last field value to variable prev here.
}
1                       ##Printing edited/non-edited lines here.
'  Input_file           ##mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Output will be as follows for provided samples.

```
1       -1      513     1478        966     1       -1
2       -1      1594        2130        537     1       -2
3       +1      2171        2539        369     1       -1
4       -1      2587        3159        573     1       -2
```

Comment: It is not exactly my desired output. Maybe I didn't explain my target correctly. I am trying to "convert" the +- signs to "add" one and "minus" one and each time to add or subtract 1 respectively from the $2. But thank you really for replying me!!!

Comment: @KGee, I thought my output comes same as shown samples output, could you please do lemme know more on same where it didn't work.

Comment: Sure! your code indeed converts the +- to +1 -1 respectively but it didn't add the values of $2( the first value to the second to the third etc) . In addition converts the values of $4 to - $4 ( add a - values to my 4th column) and add the first value $4 to the next one. In other words, I want to obtain what you did in the $4 to the $2 without converting all the values to minus. But really once again thank you for time.